# How can I use R to change my table

Tags: r, dataframe, biomart

Using **R** how would I change my table from this:

```
GeneID    GeneName    Species    Paralogues    Domains    Total
 1234      FGF1        Human         4            2         6
 5678      FGF1        Mouse         2            1         3
 9104      FGF1       Chicken        3            0         3
```

To a table that represents the total column e.g.

```
GeneName    Human    Mouse    Chicken
  FGF1        6        3         3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sathish This does not reproduce OPs expected output; have you tried this yourself?

Comment: @MauritsEvers May be this `dcast(df, GeneName ~ Species, value.var = 'Total')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::spread` to reshape from long to wide:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>% 
    select(GeneName, Species, Total) %>% 
    spread(Species, Total)
#  GeneName Chicken Human Mouse
#1     FGF1       3     6     3
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "GeneID    GeneName    Species    Paralogues    Domains    Total
 1234      FGF1        Human         4            2         6
 5678      FGF1        Mouse         2            1         3
 9104      FGF1       Chicken        3            0         3", header  = T)
```

Comment: There is no need for group_by.

Comment: @zx8754 Good point & thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dcast()` from `data.table`.

For the input:

```
text <- 
    "GeneID    GeneName    Species    Paralogues    Domains    Total
     1234      FGF1        Human         4            2         6
     5678      FGF1        Mouse         2            1         3
     9104      FGF1       Chicken        3            0         3"

my_data <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE)
```

You can transform your data with `GeneName` as `LHS` and `Species` as `RHS` with `value.var` `Total`:

```
data.table::dcast(my_data,
                  GeneName ~ Species, 
                  value.var = "Total")
```

The result:

```
  GeneName Chicken Human Mouse
1     FGF1       3     6     3
```